# What is a corresponding Java data type for Json

Tags: java, json

What data structure in Java is following piece of Json? Is it a map, an array, a list? Note there are no quotes on the right size.

```
segmentList : [{
segmentStockName : "Colombia Stock Exchange",
segmentName : "Equity Market",
segmentStockExchangeId : "CO-BVC"
}],
```

Answer (score -1):

for this json:

```
String json = "{ segmentList : [{\n" +
        "segmentStockName : \"Colombia Stock Exchange\",\n"+
        "segmentName : \"Equity Market\",\n"+
        "segmentStockExchangeId : \"CO-BVC\"\n"+
        "}]}";
```

I create following code

```
import java.util.List;

public class MyObject {
    private List<SegmentList> segmentList;

    public List<SegmentList> getSegmentList() {
        return segmentList;
    }

    public void setSegmentList(List<SegmentList> segmentList) {
        this.segmentList = segmentList;
    }

}

public class SegmentList {
    private String segmentStockName;
    private String segmentName;
    private String segmentStockExchangeId;
    public String getSegmentStockName() {
        return segmentStockName;
    }
    public void setSegmentStockName(String segmentStockName) {
        this.segmentStockName = segmentStockName;
    }
    public String getSegmentName() {
        return segmentName;
    }
    public void setSegmentName(String segmentName) {
        this.segmentName = segmentName;
    }
    public String getSegmentStockExchangeId() {
        return segmentStockExchangeId;
    }
    public void setSegmentStockExchangeId(String segmentStockExchangeId) {
        this.segmentStockExchangeId = segmentStockExchangeId;
    }   
}
```

I know you want to get it deserialized automatically but i do it manually

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    // Needed to hande a json without quotes on field names
    mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    MyObject tipo = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
    tipo.getSegmentList();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // catch it
}
```

And it works.

Comment: I can't change Json, it comes from a webservice and it's ok. There is more, I just copied a problematic piece. I want it to be parsed automatically by Jackson, no mappers

Comment: @jarosik the snippet you have in the question is not a proper JSON, please update

Comment: I only need to map a segmentList

Comment: I don't understand down vote, anyway, a getter and setter is needed for MyObject fields and for SegmentList fields

Comment: Neither do I, there's clearly someone who don't get this problem. I thought this would be an easy one. I will try to do some research on my own and come back with an answer. Thanks for help